# string '[a b c]' into a list python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have this string `[a b c]` (an array I loaded in from a csv). I want to turn this string into an array `[a, b, c]`

Any thoughts? I tried `ast.literal_eval` but I get an invalid syntax error

Comment: This should likely be solved upstream.

Comment: @pp_ no, because that's not a valid literal, hence the error

Comment: @MaxU Did you read the last part of the question?

Comment: SOLVED!  I will just use .strip('[') and .strip(']') and then .split(' ') to turn it into an array. Thanks!

Comment: f = '[a b c'] ; f = f.strip('['); f=f.strip(']'); f=f.zplit(' ')

Comment: @DavidVilla that's not a good solution, what if your string looks like this? '["hello World" "hello" "World"]'? Then splitting by ' ' will break it. As I said, you should not have to parse this string in the first place.

Comment: @DavidVilla: you can write an answer for your own question using the form below

Comment: @timgeb It's possible that his input can't be in that form.

Comment: @mbomb007 that's what I am trying to find out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do `str=str[1:-1].split(' ')`

`str[1:-1]` should remove the first and last characters, the brackets, then `split(' ')` makes a list split up by what you give it.

If your csv data comes in with commas between values, then use `.split(', ')`

Edit: Just wrote it up quick to be sure and that should do what your looking for

```
str = "[a b c]"
str=str[1:-1].split(' ')
print str
```

Prints the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 6):

Something like this? Use `str.strip` to remove the start and end `[`, `]`, then split on spaces.

```
>>> '[a b c]'.strip('[]').split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: fantastic that does exactly what i want

Comment: what about '["a b" "c" "d"]'?

Comment: @timgeb I agree it isn't perfect, but I was just going off the provided data in the question

Comment: It should be just `strip('[]')`. I'm not sure what those backslashes are for.

Comment: @timgeb: nobody said that `["a b" "c" "d"]` is a valid input

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini that's the problem, nobody said what a, b and c can be.

Comment: @interjay Was thinking regex was needed

Comment: Whoops, my bad guys :D